# How do I add phone number & email validation to Kendo-UI Grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

Given the grid supplied in the code below, how do I set validation on the **phone** and **email** to take advantage of the validation and masked input features kendo provides on this page (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/maskedtextbox/index)?

For example, if the user types in 5628103322, it should format it as (562)810-3322 as the demo on their page shows.  Also if a number that was not entered correctly it should provide an error message.

Same for email, how do we do this?

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/api",
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read:  {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies/update",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies/destroy",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            create: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies/create",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            /* the e event argument will represent the following object:

            {
                errorThrown: "Unauthorized",
                sender: {... the Kendo UI DataSource instance ...}
                status: "error"
                xhr: {... the Ajax request object ...}
            }

            */
            //alert("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
        },
        autoSync: false,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        selectable: "multiple cell",
        allowCopy: true,
        columnResizeHandleWidth: 6,
        schema: {
            total: "itemCount",
            data: "items",
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    name: { validation: { required: true } },
                    phone: { type: "string" },
                    email: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        height: 550,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: {
            mode: "multiple",
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "name", title: "Company Name" },
            { field: "phone", title:"Phone" },
            { field: "email", title:"Email" },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operations", width: "240px" }
        ],
        editable: "popup"
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE::

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: {
            mode: "multiple",
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "name", title: "Company Name" },
            { 
                field: "phone",
                title: "Phone",
                editor: function(container, options){
                    var input = $('<input type="tel" data-tel-msg="Invalid Phone Number!" class="k-textbox"/>');
                    input.attr("name", options.field);
                    input.kendoMaskedTextBox({
                        mask: "(999) 000-0000"
                    });
                    input.appendTo(container);
                }
            },
            { 
                field: "email",
                title: "Email",
                editor: function(container, options){
                    var input = $('<input type="email" data-email-msg="Invalid email!" class="k-textbox"/>');
                    input.attr("name", options.field);
                    input.appendTo(container);
                }
            },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operations", width: "240px" }
        ],
        editable: "popup"
    });
```

the grid code above has changed, it almost works perfectly now thanks to the answer below, now I just need to figure out how to add validation to the phone number and email fields so input is required, and correct input.

**UPDATE #2**

The code below now works perfectly thanks to the answer, just wanted to share it to others that might need help.  Something interesting to note is the model rule phonerule has to be named whatever the text in the middle between the dashes of this is `data-phonerule-msg`.  I'm guessing Kendo-UI must look for that when looking for custom rules.

```
<div id="grid" style="height:100%;"></div>
<script>
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
      kendo.resize($("#grid"));
    });

    var crudServiceBaseUrl = "/api",
    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read:  {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            update: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies/update",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            destroy: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies/destroy",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            create: {
                url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/companies/create",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            },
            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            /* the e event argument will represent the following object:

            {
                errorThrown: "Unauthorized",
                sender: {... the Kendo UI DataSource instance ...}
                status: "error"
                xhr: {... the Ajax request object ...}
            }

            */
            //alert("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
            console.log("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
        },
        autoSync: false,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        selectable: "multiple cell",
        allowCopy: true,
        columnResizeHandleWidth: 6,
        schema: {
            total: "itemCount",
            data: "items",
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                    name: { validation: { required: true } },
                    phone: { 
                        type: "string",
                        validation: { 
                            required: true,
                            phonerule: function(e){
                                if (e.is("[data-phonerule-msg]"))
                                {
                                    var input  = e.data('kendoMaskedTextBox');
                                    //If we reached the end of input then it will return -1 which means true, validation passed
                                    //Otherwise it won't === -1 and return false meaning all the characters were not entered.
                                    return input.value().indexOf(input.options.promptChar) === -1;
                                }
                                return true; //return true for anything else that is not data-phonerule-msg
                            } 
                        } 
                    },
                    email: { type: "string", validation: { required: true, email:true } }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        groupable: true,
        sortable: {
            mode: "multiple",
            allowUnsort: true
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        pageable: {
            refresh: true,
            pageSizes: true,
            buttonCount: 5
        },
        reorderable: true,
        resizable: true,
        columnMenu: true,
        filterable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "name", title: "Company Name" },
            { 
                field: "phone",
                title: "Phone",
                editor: function(container, options){
                    //pattern="[(][0-9]{3}[)] [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"
                    var input = $('<input type="tel" data-phonerule-msg="Invalid Phone Number!" class="k-textbox"  required />');
                    input.attr("name", options.field);
                    input.kendoMaskedTextBox({
                        mask: "(999) 000-0000"
                    });
                    input.appendTo(container);
                }
            },
            { 
                field: "email",
                title: "Email",
                editor: function(container, options){
                    var input = $('<input type="email" data-email-msg="Invalid email!" class="k-textbox" required/>');
                    input.attr("name", options.field);
                    input.appendTo(container);
                }
            },
            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Operations", width: "240px" }
        ],
        editable: "popup"
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add to column definition custom editor with validation attributes:

```
{
    field: "email",
    title:"Email",
    editor: function(container, options) {
        var input = $('<input type="email" data-email-msg="Invalid email!" class="k-textbox"/>');
        input.attr("name", options.field);
        input.appendTo(container);
    }
}
```

**Update**: phone validation:
add this attribute to phone input ("phonerule" - is the name of custom validation rule):

```
data-phonerule-msg="Invalid phone!"
```

add custom validation rule to `schema.model.fields.phone`:

```
phone: {
    type: "string",
    validation: {
        phonerule: function(e) {
            if (e.is("[data-phonerule-msg]"))
            {
                var input  = e.data('kendoMaskedTextBox');
                return input.value().indexOf(input.options.promptChar) === -1;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: trying this now, didn't know about that feature.

Comment: yup, this is what I needed, how would this work for the phone number? and in particular assigning the mask to the phone number input?

Comment: I updated my question with what I think your approach was trying to get me to do with the phone number, but not sure how to do the validation? It does work and show the mask now but you can enter the data half way press update and no error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to add mobile and email validation -

```
schema: {
        model: {
            id: "id",
            fields: {                   
                mobile: {
                    editable: true, validation: {
                        required: true,
                        Mobilevalidation: function (input) {
                            if (input.is("[name='mobile']")) {

                                if ((input.val()) == "") {
                                    input.attr("data-Mobilevalidation-msg", "Mobile number required");
                                    return /^[A-Z]/.test(input.val());
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (/^\d+$/.test(input.val())) {
                                        if (input.val().length == 10) {
                                            return true;
                                        } else {
                                            input.attr("data-Mobilevalidation-msg", "Mobile number is invalid");
                                            return /^[A-Z]/.test(input.val());
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else {
                                        input.attr("data-Mobilevalidation-msg", "Mobile number is invalid");
                                        //alert(/^[A-Z]/.test(input.val()));
                                        return /^[A-Z]/.test(input.val());
                                    }
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }

                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: { editable: true, type: "email", validation: { required: true } },
            }
        }
    }
```